# Ecell value for non spontaneous reaction

Tags: electrochemistry, experimental-chemistry

I've done my electroplating experiment but got stuck to calculate my E cell value. [image]

So my equations are like these coz I used copper stripes and copper sulphate solution. Some website says E cell can't be 0 but it has to be -0.68V as it is -0.34-(+0.34)V which kinda make sense because it is non spontaneous reaction. But other websites are like it should be 0 because there is only copper reacting. Most of my classmates are using 0V as well so I don't know what to do. Thanks

Comment: This is kinda missing the point - only potential here is forced by outside source, so yeah, you could say it's zero - it's probably not *completely* true - that would be idealised situation, but it's not like you get much current if you just stick two ends of copper wire into water.

Comment: It is kind of concentration cell with potential difference $\Delta E = \frac {0.059}{2}\log{\left(\dfrac{c(\ce{Cu^2+},c)}{c(\ce{Cu^2+},\mathrm{a})}\right)}$

Answer (score -1):

The redox potential of all electrodes depend on the concentration of the ions in solution. For Copper, it is $+0.34$ V when and only when the concentration of $\ce{Cu^{2+}}$ is equal to $1.000 M$. During the electrolysis, the concentration in contact with the electrodes is different from what it is in the bulk solution. This is why you should measure a voltage which is  $> 0.00$ V.

Comment: It doesn't matter. He's effectively not conducting any reaction. Delta G is zero and so is potential.

Comment: @Mithoron. It does matter. The author states that he was conducting a reaction. He says that **I've done my electroplating experiment**. So it may happen that the copper concentration against the anode is higher than its value in the bulk solution. And it is lower at the cathode. And Poutnik is right : it is similar to a concentration cell

Comment: Do you know how electroplating works? It's driven by external current source - a battery, or something else, is creating the actual potential difference. Some minuscule conc. issues can only cloud the picture here.

Comment: @Mithoron. Of course I know how electroplating  works, and I agree about your interpretation.